# Is it possible to turn off the internal screen of iPad M1 and only use external monitor?

Tags: ipados

Can iPad M1 be configured so that the screen is not used and only external display is used? A related question is is it possible to wake up and login to iPad only using USB keyboard connected to Type-C docking station? There are similar questions about MacBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't turn off the iPad's display. Pressing the keys of an attached USB keyboard should wake the iPad.